# What version of Cordova should I use with Ionic 1.7.16

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have just started to work on an old Ionic app and nobody knows anything about it.
From the code I can see that it's build with version 1.xx. I have installed the last Ionic 1 version 1.7.16 and used N to switch to node 8 lts.

What version of Cordova should I used with Ionic, and where can I find the version 1 Ionic repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ionic 1.7 Cordova version  >=4.2.0